# Using Passenger with dynamic mass virtual hosting/userdirs

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I already have an apache webserver set up, and it is working for PHP.

It has no static VirtualHosts set up, and dynamically routes all requests.

A request for http://example.com/ would be served from the document root `/var/www/example.com` (VirtualDocumentRoot), and a request for http://example.com/~user/ would be served from the document root `/home/user/public_html` (mod_userdir). The latter works no matter what the domain.

I would like to be able to serve Ruby on Rails applications, from the root of a document root, or from a subdirectory, using Phusion Passenger. However, it requires me to add some lines to the `<VirtualHost>` directive, which obviously isn't there.

I would prefer a solution that does not require root to deploy an application, but this is not critical. I also do not mind a solution that does not use Passenger, if I have the same ease of deployment.

Comment: Wow. I got Tumbleweed, no answers. I offered a 200point bounty, no answers. I guess it's time to give up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem possible. Passenger is completely incompatible with userdirs, and with VirtualDocumentRoot, a separate VirtualHost is required.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to write a location module in mod_perl that dynamically updates the virtualhost environment (not the container) on a per-request basis.  That's how we handled 404s for sites that weren't set up prior to the client logging in via ftp.

Comment: Define "virtualhost environment", please. If you mean sites-enabled or an equivalent, we're not using it. Otherwise, yes, I could simply write a script to create a VirtualHost for each user

Comment: with mass_virtual, you can affect the thread and dynamically add directives without needing a VirtualHost container.  It affects the context of the request on a per-request basis, which will allow you to do exactly what you need to do.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand, and Google isn't being very helpful. Please could you post an example script?